# How do I connect to postgresql with gorm?

Tags: go

How do I connect to postgresql with gorm? (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" (SQLSTATE 28P01))

```
package model

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var db *gorm.DB

func init() {
    var err error
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Tokyo"
    db, err =  gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
      panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
    db.AutoMigrate(&Todo{})
}
```

Comment: Did you try supplying a password?

Comment: As in the log, I think you should check the `username` and the `password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this instead : Use Sprintf to declare dsn

```
host := "localhost"
user := "postgres"
password := ""
dbname := "DBNAME"
port := "5432"

dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s user=%s password=%s dbname=%s port=%s sslmode=disable",
    host, user, password, dbname, port)
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{
    SkipDefaultTransaction: true,
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

and check the database connection use :

```
func TestConnect(t *testing.T) {
//your DB setup function
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In my case using windows as the OS, I had to uninstall postgres.

then open docker desktop and a terminal and create a container with:

1. docker run --name some_name -e POSTGRES_USER= your_name -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD= your_password -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
2. docker exec -it some_name bash
3. psql -U your_name --password (press enter and enter the password)
4. CREATE DATABASE db_name;
5. \c db_name (press enter and enter the password)

Done. Don't close the terminal, use another and execute the program.